# The 3rd term of a Taylor expansion, where $n=4$. Checking the result for $f(x,y) = e^{xy}\sin(x^2y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to write Taylor expansion term, for $n=4, k=3$. At a point $M=(1;\pi)$ for the function: $f(x,y) = e^{xy}\sin(x^2y)$.

$$f(x,y)= {\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}} \left[ \left(\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right)\left. \frac{\partial f}{ \partial x^{n-k}\partial y^k }\right\vert_{M} (x-x_0)^{n-k}(y-y_0)^k \right]$$

I already did all the derivatives, just want to make sure whether my result is correct.

$$f(1;\pi)=\frac{1}{3!}(-4e^{\pi})(x-1)(y-\pi)$$

Comment: What are $n$ and, especially, $k$?

Comment: I did not check but I suppose that $(x-\pi)$ could be $(y-\pi)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici True.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Now I updated the post, so it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the  two variables Taylor expansion has the ${1\over n!}$ factors missing. The correct formula is
$$f(x,y)\rightsquigarrow\sum_{n=0}^\infty{1\over n!}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}{\partial^n f\over\partial x^{n-k}\partial y^k}\biggr|_{(1,\pi)} (x-1)^{n-k}(y-\pi)^k\ .$$
According to this formula the term you want is
$${1\over4!}{4\choose 3}{\partial^4 f\over\partial x\partial y^3}\biggr|_{(1,\pi)} (x-1)(y-\pi)^3\ .$$
We therefore have to compute ${\partial^4 f\over\partial x\partial y^3}$. Mathematica obtained
$$\eqalign{{\partial^4 f\over\partial x\partial y^3}&=e^{xy} x^2 \bigl((12x-6x^3+5x^2y-7x^4y)\cos(x^2y)\cr   &\qquad\qquad+(3-15x^2+xy-9x^3y+2x^5y)\sin(x^2y)\bigr)\ ,\cr}$$
so that
$${\partial^4 f\over\partial x\partial y^3}\biggr|_{(1,\pi)}=e^\pi(-6+2\pi)\ .$$
It follows that your term is
$$\left({\pi\over3}-1\right)e^\pi(x-1)(y-\pi)^3\ .$$

Comment: Thank you for a reply, shouldn't there be also $\frac{1}{n!}$$ in the equation?

Comment: @user: $\ {1\over4!}\,{4\choose3}={1\over6}$.